# openACC passing a list of struct

Tags: c, struct, openacc, pgi, pgcc

I have a C program to find whether 2 sets of polygons are overlapped. User input 2 sets of polygon (each set of data has several thousands polygons) and the program see which polygon in set1 overlap with which polygon in set2

I have 2 struct like these:

```
struct gpc_vertex  /* Polygon vertex */
{
    double          x;
    double          y;
};

struct gpc_vertex_list  /* Polygon contour */
{
    int pid;    // polygon id
    int             num_vertices;
    double *mbr;   // minimum bounding rectangle of the polygon, so always 4 elements

};
```

I have the following segment of code:

```
#pragma acc kernels copy(listOfPolygons1[0:polygonCount1], listOfPolygons2[0:polygonCount2], listOfBoolean[0:dump])
for (i=0; i<polygonCount1; i++){
    polygon1 = listOfPolygons1[i];

    for (j=0; j<polygonCount2; j++){

        polygon2 = listOfPolygons2[j];
        idx = polygonCount2 * i + j;

        listOfBoolean[idx] = isRectOverlap(polygon1.mbr, polygon2.mbr);  // line 115

    }
}
```

listOfPolygons1 and listOfPolygons2 are (as the name implied) an array of gpc_vertex_list.
listOfBoolean is an array of int.
the mbr of the 2 polygons are checked to see if they are overlapped, and the function "isRectOverlap" return 1 if they are, 0 if they are not and put the value to listOfBoolean

**Problem**
The code can compile but not able to run. It returns the following error:

```
call to cuEventSynchronize returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution
```

**My observation**
The program can compile and run by changing line 115 to this:

```
isRectOverlap(polygon1.mbr, polygon2.mbr); // without assigning value to listOfBoolean
```

or this:

```
listOfBoolean[idx] = 5; // assigning an arbitrary value
```

(though the result is wrong, but at least, it can run)

**Question**
Both "isRectOverlap" and "listOfBoolean" do not seem to produce the problem if value is not passed from "isRectOverlap" to "listOfBoolean"
Does anyone know why it can't run if I assign the return value from "isRectOverlap" to "listOfBoolean"?

isRectOverlap function is like this:

```
int isRectOverlap(double *shape1, double *shape2){

    if (shape1[0] > shape2[2] || shape2[0] > shape1[2]){
        return 0;
    }

    if (shape1[1] < shape2[3] || shape2[1] < shape1[3]){
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;

}
```

The program has no problem when not running in OpenACC

Thanks for helping

Comment: Is it CUDA? Indicate in the tags.

Comment: i don't think so? It doesn't have CUDA code. Sorry I am new to parallel programming.

Comment: I see `cuEventSynchronize`, which looks like cuda to me.... Well, I might be wrong, as I am not familiar with this OpenACC

Comment: OpenACC and CUDA have some connection so there may be something they share to use, but anyways thank you for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When aggregate data types are used in an OpenACC data clause, a shallow copy of the type is performed.  What's most likely happening here is that when the listOfPolygons arrays are copied to the device, "mbr" will contain host addresses.  Hence, the program will give an illegal address error when a "mbr" is accessed.

Given the comment says that "mbr" will always be 4, the simplest thing to do is make "mbr" a fixed size array of size 4.

Assuming you're using PGI compilers with an NVIDIA device, a second method is to use CUDA Unified Memory by compiling "-ta=tesla:managed".  All dynamic memory would be handled by the CUDA runtime and allow host addresses to be accessed on the device.  The caveats being that it's only available for dynamic data, your whole program can only use as much memory as available on the device, and it may slow down your program.  http://www.pgroup.com/lit/articles/insider/v6n2a4.htm

A third option is to perform a deep copy of the aggregate type to the device.  I can post an example if you decide to go this route.  I also talk about the subject as part of a presentation I did at GTC2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWLmZt_u5u4

Comment: I am interested in the third solution. In fact I implemented deep copy (if I did it right) to form "listOfPolygons". Can you show me an example of solution 3? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified example.  The key is to use unstructured data regions at the same spots where you allocate the host data.  First allocate the array of structs and create or copyin the array to the device.  Here I just create the array so the device data is garbage, but if I did a copyin, then a shallow copy would occur and the host addresses for "mbr" would be copied to the device.  To fix this, you need to create each "mbr" on the device.  The compiler will then assign, "attach", the device "mbr" pointer thus overwriting the garbage/host pointer value. Once "mbr" has valid device pointers, they can be deferenced on the device.

```
% cat example_struct.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef N
#define N 1024
#endif

typedef struct gpc_vertex_list
{
    int pid;    // polygon id
    int num_vertices;
    double *mbr;   // minimum bounding rectangle of the polygon, so always 4 elements

} gpc_vertex_list;

gpc_vertex_list * allocData(size_t size);
int deleteData(gpc_vertex_list * A, size_t size);
int initData(gpc_vertex_list *Ai, size_t size);

#pragma acc routine seq
int isRectOverlap(double * mbr) {
    int result;
    result = mbr[0];
    result += mbr[1];
    result += mbr[2];
    result += mbr[3];
    return result;
}

int main() {
    gpc_vertex_list *A;
    gpc_vertex_list B;
    size_t size, i;
    int * listOfBoolean;
    size = N;
    A=allocData(size);
    initData(A,size);
    listOfBoolean = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);

#pragma acc parallel loop present(A) copyout(listOfBoolean[0:size])  private(B)
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
       B = A[i];
       listOfBoolean[i] = isRectOverlap(B.mbr);
    }

    printf("result: %d %d %d\n",listOfBoolean[0], listOfBoolean[size/2], listOfBoolean[size-1]);
    free(listOfBoolean);
    deleteData(A, size);
    exit(0);
}

gpc_vertex_list * allocData(size_t size) {
    gpc_vertex_list * tmp;
    tmp = (gpc_vertex_list *) malloc(size*sizeof(gpc_vertex_list));
/* Create the array on device.  */
#pragma acc enter data create(tmp[0:size])
    for (int i=0; i< size; ++i) {
       tmp[i].mbr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*4);
/* create the member array on the device */
#pragma acc enter data create(tmp[i].mbr[0:4])
    }
    return tmp;
}

int deleteData(gpc_vertex_list * A, size_t size) {
/* Delete the host copy. */
    for (int i=0; i< size; ++i) {
#pragma acc exit data delete(A[i].mbr)
        free(A[i].mbr);
    }
#pragma acc exit data delete(A)
    free(A);
}

int initData(gpc_vertex_list *A ,size_t size) {
    size_t i;
    for (int i=0; i< size; ++i) {
       A[i].pid = i;
       A[i].num_vertices = 4;
       for (int j=0; j<4;++j) {
           A[i].mbr[j]=(i*4)+j;
       }
       #pragma acc update device(A[i].pid,A[i].num_vertices,A[i].mbr[0:4])
    }
}
% pgcc example_struct.c -acc -Minfo=accel
isRectOverlap:
     20, Generating acc routine seq
main:
     39, Generating copyout(listOfBoolean[:size])
         Generating present(A[:])
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         40, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
     39, Local memory used for B
allocData:
     55, Generating enter data create(tmp[:size])
     59, Generating enter data create(tmp->mbr[:4])
deleteData:
     67, Generating exit data delete(A->mbr[:1])
     70, Generating exit data delete(A[:1])
initData:
     83, Generating update device(A->mbr[:4],A->pid,A->num_vertices)
% a.out
result: 6 8198 16374
```

Comment: Mat thanks for the example. What does the "private(B)" clause use for? I read the doc and it said "A copy of each variable in list is allocated for each gang." but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: It means that every vector will get it's own copy of the variable.  If this was a gang loop, then each gang will have a private copy that's shared across vectors.   By default, arrays are shared while scalars are private.  So normally "B" would be private by default, however since it's mbr member is being passed to a subroutine, the compiler must assume that there could be other references to it, so to be safe, makes it shared by default.  Hence why I put it into a private clause.

Comment: Mat thanks a lot!! Your example is really really helpful! My program can compile and run successfully now. However my case is a little bit different: when I allocate data, I do not know how many elements I will have until I traverse the whole input file. So my code keeps realloc-ing the array until the input file ends. In your code, you assume the size is known (in allocData function). So you can create the whole array in the device in advance and update the values later. Is there any openACC pragma to handle my case?

Comment: I'd traverse the file creating the host side data structure.  Then walk the structure again building the mirror device structure.  It's not necessary to couple the host and device side allocation, I just like it for convenience.  You can do something similar to realloc by creating a temp array on the device, using "acc_memcpy" to copy the old data to the new, and then deleting the old device array.  However if you don't use the data until after you traverse the file, there shouldn't be a need perform a realloc on the device.