# openacc struct in loop and if-statement

Tags: loops, struct, openacc, pgi

I have the following code:

```
#pragma acc data present(listOfPolygons1, listOfPolygons2, polygon1, polygon2) copy(listOfBoolean[0:numOfPolygonsPair])
#pragma acc parallel loop
    // do point-in-polygon in this nested loop
    for (i=0; i<polygonCount1; i++){

        polygon1 = listOfPolygons1[i];

        for (j=0; j<polygonCount2; j++){

            polygon2 = listOfPolygons2[j];

            idx = polygonCount2 * i + j;

            if (listOfBoolean[idx]==0){
                // don't even have an intersection
                continue;
            } else {
                // do point-in-polygon test

                for (k=0; k<polygon2.num_vertices; k++){  // line 139

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

"polygon1" and "polygon2" are struct.
"listOfPolygons1" and "listOfPolygons2" are struct array with a list of "polygon1" and "polygon2" correspondingly.
"listOfBoolean" is a array of int
both "listOfPolygons1" and "listOfPolygon2" are deep-copied to the accelerator and used successfully in previous loop (code not shown here)

the code can be compiled but when run, it produces the following error message:

```
call to cuEventSynchronize returned error 716: Misaligned address
```

**My observation**
The problem seems to be in line 139. 
When I use "k<polygon2.num_vertices", it produced the error I mentioned. 
But if I change the line to this:

```
 for (k=0; k<listOfPolygons2[j].num_vertices; k++) // not using struct "polygon2"
```

(update 1) or this:

```
for (k=0; k<polygon1.num_vertices; k++) // use polygon1.num_vertices instead
```

The program can compile and run successfully

Why is that and how can I use struct "polygon2" here?

Comment: Shouldn't polygon1 and polygon2 be private to each thread?  As it is now, every thread is sharing the same variables.  While I can't be sure without a reproducing example, my best guess is that you're getting a read/write collision where one thread is writing to polygon2 while another is reading from it and this collision is causing the error.

Comment: Go back an look at the example code I wrote up for you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779782/openacc-passing-a-list-of-struct where I privatized the "B" struct.

Comment: thanks Mat for the suggestion but it still does not work. Another thing I observed is, if I change "k<polygon2.num_vertices" to "k<polygon1.num_vertices", it is also able to run without error (thought the result is wrong). So it seems particularly that the "polygon2" is causing the problem. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Not off hand.  I'll need to see the full code.  Can you post or send to PGI Customer Service (trs@pgroup.com) a reproducing example?

Comment: thanks Mat. I just sent it.